# Why varible allto give 21?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I made a loop to collect numbers in the array 
I put a value that equal to 0 
and gives me 21 because every time 0 will be added to every single element in the array and collect them and give us 20
but if I put the value to 1 
it gives me 21, but it should give me 24 
because I added 1 to every element in the array ? or am I wrong
why it gives me 21?

```js
var num = [5,5,5,5];
var allto = 1;
var total = 0;

for(var i= 0; i<num.length; i++) {
  allto = allto +  num[i];
  total = total + num[i];
}
alert(allto); // == 21
alert(total); // == 20
```

Comment: Oh, I see. You think that the `1` will be added every time an assignment is made. That's not how initializations work. It just starts with `1` and then you replace it with `5` more on every iteration. In other words, `1` is a starting value. It has no other effect on any other operations that come later.

Comment: ...this is just like your simple mathematics. If you have `1` and you add `5`, you get `6`. If you add `5` again, you get `11`, and so on...

Comment: its clear now thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you run above code

```
allto     |  i    |  total
___________________________
1         | -     | 0       //before loop start
6         | 0     | 5       // allto=1+5=6  and total=0+5=5
11        | 1     | 10       // allto=6+5=11  and total=5+5=10
16        | 2     | 15       // allto=11+5=16  and total=10+5=15
21        | 3     | 20       // allto=16+5=21  and total=15+5=20
```

So at the end `allto=21` and `total=20`